# How to stop video when target is lost in augmented reality ?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, augmented-reality

I have made an AR application which play video when the target is detected. But problem is that even when I place camera not in-front of the target image (No Target) its still keep playing until I go again an pause the video by clicking on the target.

Comment: Are you using Vuforia for target detection/tracking?

Comment: @Trey Using Vuforia

Answer (score 1):

If using Vuforia, there is a callback function, OnTrackingLost(), indicating that the tracker has been lost. You can stop the video in the body of this function.

If using another technology and you have to implement such a function by yourself, the obvious solution would be to use a timer. If the target image (previously recognized and tracked) is not detected for a given period of time, the tracker is lost. Again, you stop the video when you realize that the tracked image is lost.

Comment: What to code in the body of OnTrackingLost()... can you give a sort of example here

Comment: video.VideoPlayer.Stop();